# I need to pass through data from an id attriubute varible to an href attribute to complete the href route

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, bootstrap-5

I wanted to see if anyone has an idea of how to pass an id variable through to another attribute within the same tag os from another tag. I'm just trying to add a popup modal for a user to confirm before they delete another user.

```
   <a class="deleteUserBTN btn btn-outline-danger col-3" data-id="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" title="Add this item" href="#deleteUserModal">Delete User</a>

<!-- Delete User Modal -->
    <div class="modal" id="deleteUserModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
          <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                  <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
                  <h4>Are you sure you want to Delete this User?</h4>
                  <input type="text" id="user" />
              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                  <a type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="user" href="delete_user.php?delete=">Delete</a>
              </div>
          </div> 
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- End Delete User Modal -->

<script>
        $(document).on("click", ".deleteUserBTN", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var _self = $(this);
            var userID = _self.data('id');
            $("#user").val(userID);
            $(_self.attr('href')).modal('show');
        });
</script>
```

I've only been able to pass the user ID and display it in the  tag inside the modal. But I'm trying to pass the data/id to the href in the  (delete btn inside the modal) to complete the route. I would like the href to read something like:

```
href="delete_user.php?delete=36"
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: `$('#deleteUserModal a').attr('href', "delete_user.php?delete=" + userID);`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two elements with `id="user"` so give the link a different id and you can use `prop('search')`

```js
$(document).on("click", ".deleteUserBTN", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var _self = $(this);
  var userID = _self.data('id');
  $("#delete_link").prop('search', 'delete=' + userID);
  // log in console for demo only
  console.log($("#delete_link").prop('href'))
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="deleteUserBTN btn btn-outline-danger col-3" data-id="55555" title="Add this item" href="#deleteUserModal">Delete User</a>

<!-- Delete User Modal -->
<div class="modal" id="deleteUserModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <h4>Are you sure you want to Delete this User?</h4>
        <input type="text" id="user" />
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <a type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="delete_link" href="delete_user.php?delete=">Delete</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- End Delete User Modal -->
```

Answer (score 0):

wow, you sure seem to make this complicated.  You can pass the parameter either to javascript on the same page or you can pass it back to the server.  Here's how:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>href</title>
 </head>

 <body>
    <a id='myHref' href="delete_user.php?del=36">click here</a>
 </body>

 <script>
     document.getElementById("myHref").addEventListener("click", displayAttribute, false);

     function displayAttribute(event) {
       event.preventDefault();
       let url = event.target.href;
       
       let params = (new URL(url)).searchParams;
       let del = params.get('del');
       console.log(del);

/*****************************************************
  this line redirects you to delete_user.php
*****************************************************/

       location.href = new URL(url);
    }
</script>
```

Be sure to preserve log in chrome developer tools.

and here's the php script:

```
<?php
   print_r($_GET);
?>
```